# Measuring statistical significance for NYC restaurant inspection grades

Tags: statistical-significance, anova, categorical-data, chi-squared-test

I recently had a timed interview question on the following data set: https://data.cityofnewyork.us/Health/DOHMH-New-York_City-Restaurant-Inspection-Results/xx67-kt59/about The question was: is there a statistically significant relationship between the type of cuisine (American, Italian, etc.) and restaurant inspection grade (A,B,or C)?

My question is: what statistical tool would one use to solve this question? ANOVA? Chi-Squared? Other? Why?

Answer (score 0):

Please correct me if I am wrong, but I don't believe you can use ANOVA because the distribution of grades is not Normal among different restaurants. I believe the most common grade is "A".

This article goes into greater detail of pitfalls of the current grading system. http://fivethirtyeight.blogs.nytimes.com/2011/01/19/grading-new-york-restaurants-whats-in-an-a/?_r=0

This other article presents a very detailed analysis of restaurants and their grades, I would read it and perhaps steal some of their ideas to use in your analysis. https://harvarddatasciencerestaurantinspections.wordpress.com/2014/12/12/big-data-analysis-of-nyc-restaurant-inspections/ *3rd edit: This article is very advanced and there's a lot of it that I don't understand!

Comment: I agree. The data would definitely be skewed towards 'A' and not normally distributed.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful advice! Now I realize that the first rule of any interview question should be 'check to see if someone has already published on the data set'. Wish I knew that during the interview :P

Comment: Was that the only part of the interview? Well, if you're the type of person who looks up what the correct answers are after an interview, it sounds like you're already a pretty good employee :)